# ISAPI_Rewrite and Coldfusion Rules

Tags: coldfusion, isapi, isapi-rewrite

This is the first time that I am trying to use ISAPI_Rewrite and ColdFusion. My hosting company has a wiki which says I need to create an `.htaccess` file and add the following rules to it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*?\.cfm)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(/.+)? $1$4?$2=$3 [NC,LP,QSA
```

I have 8 main pages for my website:

- index.cfm
- products.cfm
- product-detail.cfm
- brands.cfm
- about.cfm
- contact.cfm
- specials.cfm
- gallery.cfm

I have done that. What I would like to know is:

1. Since I am new to this, are there any other rules that I need to define? I cannot find a decent tutorial on this matter.
2. Is there any ColdFusion code that I need to add to my Application.cfm page?

Also how would I change this:

```
products-search.cfm?filter=brand&brand_id=115
```

to

```
products-search.cfm/HKSparts
```

Like I said, this is my first time trying this out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you use iis url rewrite module instead?

Comment: Im using the option available on Hostek.com which is ISAPI_Rewrite

Comment: Are these not the same modules?

Comment: An .htaccess file is used by Apache. IIS uses a file named web.config.

Comment: The Hostek wiki says we have to use .htaccess

Comment: hostek supports iis url rewrite module! I know as I have several websites hosted with them, so you can choose which one to use!

Answer (score 0):

If it's an ISAPI_Rewrite then I'm afraid `.htaccess` is not the file. Please, see http://www.isapirewrite.com/docs/#conffile. However, if it's ISAPI_Rewrite3, the file format is correct. Try to contact HeliconTech directly. They have a very responsive support team.

Comment: You can use their FAQ - http://www.helicontech.com/forum/10648-FAQ.html to investagate if ISAPI_Rewrite3 is installed correctly